# Detox: typeText space in string

Tags: detox

I'm trying to enter text in TextInput field using detox. My test case looks like this:

```
  it('should create company', async () => {
    await element(by.id('addCompany')).tap();
    await expect(element(by.id('companyForm'))).toBeVisible();
    const companyName = element(by.id('formCompanyName'))

    companyName.typeText('Test');
    companyName.typeText(" ");
    companyName.typeText('Company');

  });
```

According to the Earlgrey docs: https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/blob/master/EarlGrey/Core/GREYKeyboard.m#L81 the space identifier is " ", but this doesn't seem to work? Other things such as backspace companyName.typeText("\b"); - work fine.

Is there a trick on how to show enter text with space in it? Or should I use the `replaceText()` function instead?

Comment: I've had better luck with the `replaceText()` function since it doesn't rely on the Simulator.app's **⌘K** toggle key being in one state or another.

Comment: Yes, I'm also using replaceText() now, but still wondering if one could use the keyboard for this somehow.